# How can i fetch data from an url with 3 params?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to fetch data from an bible api.

examples:

https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/Genesis/1/
https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/Revelation/1/14

I can change the chapters and verses with params id. but the book won't work. do i need something else then params.id for the book because it's text instead of numbers?

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="verse in verses" :key="verse.id">
      <p>{{ verse.Book + ' ' + verse.Chapter +':' + verse.Verse + ' ' + verse.Text }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  asyncData({ params, error }) {
    return axios
      .get(
        `https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/${params.id}/${params.id}/${params.id}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        return { verses: res.data };
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: *"but the book won't work"* What does that mean?

Comment: You're inserting `params.id` for book, chapter and verse.

Comment: I think Your URL should look like `https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/${params.book}/${params.chapter}/${params.verse}`. You need to make sure that You are setting these params to proper values.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in 3 distinct variables.
You are currently just passing params.id three times so if params.id = 1 the resulting URL would be

```
https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/1/1/1
```

which will at least return a 404.
To use it properly you will need to provide the 3 parameters, 2 of which will be numbers and one will be text.

So the params should be something like:

{
      chapter: 1,
      verse: 1,
      book: 'Luke'
   }

and you then access each to create the URL.

```
https://kingjames.herokuapp.com/api/bible/${params.book}/${params.chapter}/${params.verse}
```